# How Can I get Rake to use RVM's Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rake, bash

I'm trying to install an application  on Ubuntu that uses ruby. I installed RVM and Ruby 2.0 and ran `rake install`, but Rake tried using an older system version of Ruby. So I uninstalled the system version and tried running Rake again. This time it said "No such file". How do I get Rake to use RVM's ruby? Below is the output from different commands.

```
 $ rake install
sudo bundle --without production staging test levelbuilder --quiet
sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/bundle: No such file or directory
rake aborted!
...
/home/ubuntu/../rake_utils.rb:33:in `system'
..
/home/ubuntu/../rake_utils.rb:43:in `bundle_install'
/home/ubuntu/../Rakefile:198:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
..
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
...
```

The path and version look right:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p643 (2015-02-25 revision 49749) [x86_64-linux]

$ which ruby
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby
```

Here's my .bash_profile:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile    

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

and here's the bottom of .bashrc:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting.
```

Comment: If you've installed `rake` using the `gem` provided by RVM, this isn't an issue. What does `which rake` say? Is it the right path?

Comment: Ran `gem install rake` and `which rake`.  It outputs: `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/rake`. but rake install still results in the same error.

Comment: Does `bundle exec rake install` work? Normally you just do `bundle install` which depends on `which bundle` being correct.

Comment: Actually running that results in `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory` since the gemfile is in a sub-directory.

Comment: You'll need to trigger it from within the directory or it won't know what to do.

Comment: What commands did you follow to install RVM, and Ruby? If you didn't follow the directions on [RVM's install page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) then you need to read it completely and do any steps you missed. Add the output of `rvm info` to your question, formatted for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Execute `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Try using rvm gemsets. Task `rake install` does not exist unless you created it. If you don't have a Gemfile, create it. [gemfile](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html)

Comment: Consider adding further explanation about why this could be an answer.